# 3rd party games for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI all,

My client wants to integrate few games to his iPhone application.
For this concern we are ready to buy the paid or we can use the free games as well.

As far as I know the flash isn't supported in iPhone, can you show me a way how should I begin?
Is there any way to play flash games on iPhone or are there any games you would like to share with me which can be integrated in iPhone.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is this specifically about flash games? What exactly does your client want? Does he have his own games he wants ported to the iOS platform, or does he simply want a few games on his iPhone? And if so, what is wrong with the games found in the appstore?

Comment: My client simply want "Games".
:)
There are no specific needs just want to integrate few(any) games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash isn't supported on iOS platforms unfortunately.

If you want to develop games for the iPhone, you could try using the [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) API. It just had its version 1.0 released, and it should work with the latest Xcode. The only thing you need is some objective C knowledge, but you can easily pick this up by following a few [examples](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html). This is a great tutorial to get you started: [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial). Also don't forget to check the [Cocos2D programming guide.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aindex)

Good luck with your client!